# How to convert list of tuples to binary in erlang

Tags: list, binary, erlang

Suppose i have

```
Message = [{"from_email",From_Email},{"name",Name},{"text",Text}],
To=[{"to_email",ToMail},{"to_name",ToName}],
Send_Mail=[{"to",To},{"subject",Subject},{"message",Message},{"from_email",From_Email},{"from_name",From_Name}].
```

I want to convert Send_Mail into binary to parse into jason format. I am using jsx for parsing and jsx takes binary inputs.

Answer (score 3):

A quick brute-force approach:  iterate the list, recursively entering tuples and lists, converting all string-like lists to binary.

```
%% First exclude things that should be left alone:
list_to_jsx(E) when is_integer(E); is_float(E); is_atom(E); is_binary(E) -> E;

%% If converting a list, see if it can be made neatly into a 
%% binary, if so, done, if not recurse into the list.
list_to_jsx(L) when is_list(L) ->
    case catch list_to_binary(L) of
        B when is_binary(B) -> B;
        _ -> [convert(E) || E <- L]
    end;

%% If converting a tuple, convert each element:
list_to_jsx(T) when is_tuple(T) ->
    list_to_tuple([convert(E) || E <- tuple_to_list(T)]).
```

If you are confident that only 2-tuples appear in the input list, the last clause can be simplified slightly to

```
list_to_jsx({F,V}) -> {convert(F),convert(V)}.
```

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. Add `is_binary` to the first case; 2. You only need to handle 2-element tuples in the last case, which simplifies it.

Comment: Good catch, I'll edit in the `is_binary`, omitting that was an oversight.  I'll also provide an alternate form for the tuple clause.

Comment: It only can be 2-tuple-list because of  `[{Key, Value}]` format that matches josn `{Key : Value}`

Answer (score 1):

JSX has [`encode`](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx#encode12) functions to encode Erlang terms to JSON. But note that the keys should be atoms (`from_email` without quotes or in single quotes) or binaries (`<<"from_email">>`), not Erlang strings. If you are somehow stuck with the form you have, you can convert the keys (and values if necessary) into binaries with

```
[{list_to_binary(Key), if is_list(Value) -> list_to_binary(Value); true -> Value end} || {Key, Value} <- ListOfTuples]
```

If values can be JSON objects themselves, you'll need recursion. See Joe's answer for one approach.

To answer the more general question in the title:

1. If you just want to convert into a binary in some way and back, use [`erlang:term_to_binary`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-1). Works on any terms.
2. If you want to get a binary containing the string representation of the term, use `erlang:iolist_to_binary(io_lib:write(Term))`.

However, neither of these methods produce JSON.

Comment: Doesn't author ask how to convert keys from list-strings to binary-strings to use encode function later?

Comment: @Lol4t0 I don't think so? They say "convert Send_Mail into binary", where `Send_Mail` is a list of tuples. Same in the question title.

Comment: Somehow it was my impression. And the other answer is given with the same opinion in mind actually.

Comment: @Lol4t0 However, I added the answer to this just in case.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Your point on the other answer makes sense, I missed it. Fixed my comment there.

Comment: @Lol4t0 was right . i posted the question in wrong way my apologies.